# Adding event listeners dynamically

Tags: actionscript-3

Suppose I want to create a single button. This should be easy enough - just create a square, addChild to add it to the screen  and an event listener for mouse.CLICK event

```
add_btn_listeners():void
 {

   btn[0].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btn_clc1);
 }
public function btn_clc1(event:Event):void
 {
   action1();
 }
```

Suppose though that you wanted to create twenty buttons. You would then need twenty functions similar to the above btn_clc1 function with an event listener for the appropriate click.

But suppose you wanted the action to very slightly such as by index. For example, btn[0] calling action1, btn[1] calling action2, etc. in the same listener btn_clc1 listener.

A very common example of this would be mouse rollover. On rollover to highlight a square for instance, increasing the alpha layer to highlight a menu selection. The highlighted layer would depend on the index, something like: btn[index].alpha = .9;

Is there a way to reduce the number of event listeners, or code more optimally in cases like this? Most of the example's I've seen seem kind of shallow for larger cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly the type of problem that object oriented programming is designed to solve. Just create a class with the event handlers in it - then you can create as many of them as you like.

Class example:

```
public class MyButton extends Sprite
{
    public function MyButton()
    {
        graphics.beginFill(0);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, 50, 30);
        graphics.endFill();

        addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _mouse);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, _mouse);
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, _mouse);
    }

    private function _mouse(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        switch(e.type)
        {
            case MouseEvent.CLICK:
                trace("click");
            break;

            case MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER:
                alpha = 0.9;
            break;

            case MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT:
                alpha = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can create them like so:

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var btn:MyButton = new MyButton();

    btn.x = i * 60;
    addChild(btn);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is within the event object in the event handler, there is a 'target' property. This refers to the object that dispatched the event. You can cast it back in to whatever you assigned the event listener to and access it, or can just use a loop/if block to compare to figure out which button it was.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

var aButton:Sprite = new Sprite();

function clicked(inputEvent:MouseEvent):void {
    var theButton:Sprite = (Sprite) (inputEvent.target);
    trace(theButton); // traces out the sprite

    // can compare
    trace(theButton == aButton); // traces out true

    // if the had any (custom) properties, you could also access them, such as:
    trace(theButton.visible);
}
aButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clicked, false, 0, true);
```